# Protect/unprotect a Word document

Tags: office-js

Is there any way to protect/unprotected a Word document by password programmatically using `office.js` ?

I have checked the API documentation (https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/WordJs_1.4_OpenSpec/reference/word/body.md#getrangerangelocation-string) of OfficeJS. But do not get any clue.

Any types of tip/help is welcome !

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately that's not possible to achieve with the API. Please share this request in our user voice channel.

Comment: Hello, no updates as of now. Unfortunately I cannot disclose any specific dates for this. thanks.

Comment: The lack of support for protecting and unprotecting a Word document is pretty pathetic. It is 2022 and the fundamental piece of functionality such as this is still not supported, the same goes for document variables. How can it not be supported?? This pretty much seals the deal on the huge project which we planning to do in this technology - death by lack of fundamental feature support.