# Is there any way to protect/unprotected a Word document by password programmatically using office.js in memory?

Tags: javascript, office-js, office-addins

Is there any way to protect/unprotected a Word document by password programmatically using office.js ?

I gone through the some of the snipeets from [Office js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/)

Note : I have to do that in memory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Protect/unprotect a Word document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45966631/protect-unprotect-a-word-document)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's currently possible to protect/unprotect a Word document by using Office JS (Word JavaScript API). I'd suggest that you vote for this feature request in [Office Developer Platform UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback?category_id=163566) (or create a new feature request there if one doesn't already exist for this). The Office PM team uses UserVoice feedback to get a sense for overall priority/demand of various features as they plan future enhancements to the API.